Install Anaconda on Ubuntu (Linux)
I have installed Anaconda on Ubuntu and can't open the navigator:

My error is: "libpci.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
During installation I had to run: "sudo apt-get install libg1-meas-glx libeg1l-mesa libxrandr2 libxrandr2 l
ibxss1 libxcursor1 libxcomposite1 libasound2 libxi6 libxtst6"
I was unable to install libg1-mesa-glx, libg1l-mesa, and libasound2. I think this might be the issue, but I do not know how to install this missing packages.
Not sure what I need to install to open the navigator GUI successfully. I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=792d3oJaX0k

The absence of libgl1-mesa-glx and libasound2 could definitely be the issue. Why can't you install them? Do you get an error, or is apt unable to find them?

This was the issue. @nmishin

The absence of libgl1-mesa-glx and libasound2 is definitely the issue.
You need to install them, and you can verify the installation by running:
sudo ldconfig -p | grep libpci
libpci.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpci.so.3

